# Equality between sum and integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, power-series

> Show that,(where log is natural logarithm)
>
> $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(logn\ -\sum_{k=0}^n\frac 1k\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{n}\left(1-\dfrac xn\right)^nlogx\ dx$

Then

$log(n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}(n-1)^k$,

i couldn't continue with this, how can i convert the series into an integral then, any hints ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant